# How to remove dotted line in table of contents in first heading only?

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

Does someone know how to remove dotted line in first heading in TOC, so in other heading it would still be?

Example:

[image: TOC text]

Comment: Tab leader gives you a drop down to select different styles of leaders, such as dots (default), dashes, or a solid line. Select (none) to turn tab leaders off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Modify the TOC 1 style.

That controls the formatting for all level 1 TOC lines. What you want to remove is the dot leader in the tab setting for the page numbers.

Here is [information on setting tabs](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/SettingTabs.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill.

Here is an [article on TOC Tricks and Tips](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm), also by Suzanne.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I believe it is good, but problem is that I modified TOC 1 style so it would be without dots, but it doesn't fix my problem. Can you show some example on your own Microsoft Word document?

Comment: You are asking me or another volunteer, to create a document with your problem and then fix it, on a holiday in the USA. You can attach a link to a sample document here. Put it on OneDrive or DropBox. Here is my article on how to do this. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258 I added a couple of links at the bottom of the answer that may help.